# Margin collapse diffrent behavior in browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, chromium

Having this CSS code:

```
body, html{
    height: 100%;
}
.parent{
    margin: 0 100px;
}

.child{
    margin: 30px 6% 100px;
}
```

and this HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div>
            111
        </div>
        <div>
            222
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            longgg Lorem Ipsum which fits all size of the page
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

(Note that text should long enough to fill all height of the screen.)

I see different behavior in browsers and their versions, like in Firefox there IS 100px bottom margin from down of the page, BUT in Chrome (any version but last version, seems to be fixed in latest version) I see no bottom margin and the content is stick to bottom of the page.

first:
[image]

second:

[image]

My questions are:

- As far as I know according to spec first behavior is the correct one, so first of all, am I right about this?
- If this is/was a bug in any browser could you provide a link to bug tracking page of the issue, or to changelog of the version which it was fixed at?
- Aside from setting border to children, what are possible fixes to this?
- Does any CSS resetting tool fix this?

Comment: there is also the possibility  to give the bottom margin to the parent as a bottom padding to forget about it and keep going. or give a min-height to body instead height.

Comment: yeah, that's right about my third question, thanks.